# How does spring resolve method calls as beans?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, jls

Consider this code:

```
public class Bean1  {}

public class Bean2  {
    private final Bean1 bean1;

    public Bean2(Bean1 bean1){
        this.bean1 = bean1;
    }
}

@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Bean1 bean1(){
        return new AImpl(); 
    }

    @Bean 
    public Bean2 bean2() {
        return new BImpl(bean1());
    }

    @Bean
    public Bean3 bean3() {
        return new BImpl(bean1());
    }
}
```

My knowledge of Java dicates, that two references of `bean1` in `bean2` and `bean3` should be different, that, since I call the `bean1()` method twice, two different objects should be created.

However, under Spring, in the same ApplciationContext, etc. etc., both `bean2` and `bean3` will have the same reference to the same object of class `Bean1`.

How is that possible in Java? What mechanism does Spring use that allows it to somehow intercept method calls and put beans as result of those calls?

Comment: well you have indicated the bean1() method as a bean  , so spring will set it up for you in a singleton scope , so no matter how many times you are going to call bean1() method , it will return you always the same spring bean instance , a solution would be to define them as prototypes

Comment: `Bean` is just a springframework annotation; it seems here, that spring somehow modifies typical Java Language behavior by modifying what calls to methods do. I know the idea behind beans, I don't understand the mechanism used to achieve that. Your comment does not explain anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class with the `@Configurable` annotation are treated in a special way. They are [parsed using ASM](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassParser.java) and from the scanning special bean definitions are created. Basically each `@Bean` annotation is a special kind of factory bean.

Because the methods are treated as factory beans they are only invoked once (unless the scope isn't singleton of course).

Comment: I understand that, but this does not explain what and how actually executes the code and how does a normal java method call get translated to an invocation of the factory bean metod. Is there another dynamic-proxy class created based on `MyConfiguration`?

Comment: That is what the whole ASM processing is doing... What part of that didn't you understand? Factory beans are created just like a normal `FactoryBean` and applies the same rules.

Comment: After googling ASM I found and read [this article](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/manipulating-java-class-files-with-asm.html) and it gave me the answer. I was looking for something like *your class' bytecode is modified, so that each method is effectively replaced by a factory method*. Please elaborate a bit if you find the time.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration class is not executed as it.
Your class is first read by `org.springframework.asm.ClassReader`
The class `org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser` parses your configuration class. Each method annoted by `@Bean` is associated to a `org.springframework.context.annotation.BeanMethod`.